# QT VisualStudio 2013 compile crossplatform: Windows, Android

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, qt, cross-platform

I´m currently developing an application for windows desktop. In the future we would like to use it on Android tablets as well. Thats my configuration right now:

- Qt5.5 (64 bit)
- Visual Studio Professional 2013
- Windows 7
- Graphical userinterface (ui-file)

The questions are:
- Is it possible to compile it from the same source repository?
- The program includes drag and drop of items inside the program. Are those drag and drop events in android different?

Has anybody a good tutorial or tips what how to build my project for android?

Thank you very much! 
Since I haven´t found anything yet, I would write a small how to if I get it working, so others do have an idea how to do it (in case it is possible :P)

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile and run C++ code written for windows on android you:

1. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038616/qt-versions-kits-and-compilers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041221/add-qt-versions-after-installation)
2. Firsly you should know there are three tipes of architecture for android - armeabi, armeabi-v7 and x86. armeabi is older than armeabi-v7 and in older mobile devices is used armeabi.
3. If you have any shared libraries or static libraries(.lib and .dll) linked in your project you should find their android equivalent binaries(.a and .so) or compile them from source with gcc compiller.
4. In this way you can use the GUI of you project, but you should remake it bacause of the resolution and to look more native on mobile. The other code should run successfully.
5. You should read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) - install jdk, android sdk, ndk, apache ant and ADB if you are going to use phisical device. Set in tools->Options-> Android the paths to jdk,sdk,ndk and ant. Don't forget to start SDK manager.exe
6. Now you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nkhlhBwkjk) video and see how to create android virtual device for example Nexus S, run it. Try to run android example for start to see if it works at all. Then you can try to run simple code with the use of your shared libs compile for android to see if they work.
7. Don't forget in .pro file if your library begin with "lib" you must miss it [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953855/qt-5-5-1-so-library-with-android)

I have not used drag and drop events but if they are part of QT library they should run. I did mentioned in the first point qt versions, kits and compillers - there are three versions of qt framework for android - QT for android armv7, armv5(this is armeabi), x86 and you can combine it with GCC 4.9 compiler into kit(I am using QT 5.5.1).

Comment: Hi,
thats what I was looking for! Thank you very much! Since it´s my last week here as an intern, I won´t be able to test it, but I´ll hand everything over this week and the next intern will face this task! So it will be useful!
BR Martin

Comment: I marked this topic as solved, since it seems to be possible to run the application on Android - even though I didn´t test it :p

PS: If anybody has additional comments, feel free to extend the answer! Some people might need more information.