# QT versions, kits and compilers

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, compilation, tesseract

I am new in QT and was wondering what is the difference between QT versions, kits and compilers. In my "Build & Run" tab are avilable:

Kits:

- Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit2
- Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit

Qt Versions:

- Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit2  and some qmake.exe path
- Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit  and some qmake.exe path

Compilers:

- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(amd64)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86_amd64)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86_arm)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(amd64_arm)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(x86)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(x86_amd64)
- Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK (ARMV4I)
- Windows Mobile 5.0 Smartphone SDK (ARMV4I)

I tried to link tesseract 3.02 with QT(I have linked it with Visual Studio 2013 successfuly before that) but very strange errors like below appeared:

[image]

But then I have remembered in VS 2013 this was becouse of the use of 32 bit libs in 64 bit compilation. The Qt setup I have downloaded is "qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.2-2-online.exe" i.e. it is 32 bit. And now I am very comfused - what bits I am using right now for my project 64 or 32, what is the difference between 64bit and 64bit2, which must be 32 bit - the compiler, the qt version or the kits. If someone can give simple explanation together with for what are kits,qt version and compilers used(of course I know what is compiler, but cant get the reference between SDK and compiler).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt versions are Qt packages that you download from digia (libraries, source code, documentation, etc...), compilers are the compilers you have on your machine and kits are valid combinations of these two.

In your case you have:

- Qt 5.4.2 64bit
- Qt 5.5.0 64bit
- Msvc both 32bit and 64bit

you can combine the two Qt versions (that are 64bit) with the 64bit version of the msvc compiler, but not with its 32bit version.

Comment: OK and what about the setup - it is x86. My QT application is 32 bit(checked in about), but the used QT packages are 64 bits. Is it not strange 32 bit application to have the power of using 64 bit libraries and compiling 64 bit projects?

Comment: No not so strange really, Qt prefers to ship its binaries in 32 bit so that they can run on 32 and 64 but do not forget that Qt is not a compiler it's a framework built to run with many compilers on several platforms.. BTW if you prefer to have QtCreator 64 bits you can download sources and compile it yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to add new QT Versions after installation without the necessity of reinstallation like in my case I need 32bit QT Version for the combination?

Comment: the Qt installer should permit to add packages to the current installation IIRC

Comment: No, it does not support such thing. It gives 'The folder you selected already exists and contain an installation. Choose a different target for installation.' error.

Comment: In my Qt 5,.5 installation directory I have the MaintenanceToole.exe program which you can use to add/remove components to Qt installation. Personally I've installed both 32 and 64bit versions of Qt 5.5.0