# How to add more Qt versions after installation?

Tags: qt, installation, version

I have installed the opensource Qt 5.5.0 with the following settings:

Kits:

```
Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit2
Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit
```

Qt Versions:

```
Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit2 and some qmake.exe path
Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit and some qmake.exe path
```

Compilers:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(amd64)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86_amd64)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(x86_arm)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(amd64_arm)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(x86_amd64)
Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK (ARMV4I)
Windows Mobile 5.0 Smartphone SDK (ARMV4I)
```

But now I want to add 32 bit Qt versions to be able to combine them with x86 compilers in a 32 bit kit like Lucacox mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039206/5325058) without the necessity to preinstall Qt from the setup again.

I have tried from `tools->Build & Run->Qt Versions->Add` but don't know if `.qmake` is enough and where to find it (based on the answer of Lucacox above I think it is not - maybe at least downloading the version from somewhere is needed).

The installer does not allow adding Qt Versions in the same installation:

[image: Qt installation error: "The folder you selected already exists and contains an installation. Choose a different target for installation."]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily accomplish adding specific standard Qt builds with Qt Maintenance Tool. As long as you are on Windows find one by typing: "Windows+S Qt Maint...", or by finding QT in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel and clicking "Change".

[image: Selecting Qt prebuilt framework for download]

Mind that you can use one Qt Creator with different prebuilt target Qt. I do that for both 32 and 64 bit without replacing the tool itself. It is all about choosing proper [Compiler Kit](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html) and choosing/[adding Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html) for your project target.

Comment: The maintance tool is located in "Qt_installation_dir/MaintenanceTool.exe". The second method to run it in windows is "control panel -> Programs and Features -> find the qt program -> right button on it -> change".

Comment: I want to add that sometimes there is no link to the repository in the maintenance tool. If so you can add them in the settings by just add the url  [http://download.qt-project.org/](http://download.qt-project.org/) or ( [http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/](http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/) etc.)
one should also mention, that this might not work if you have installed only one specific qt version on the first hand. I had this problem and only got a 5.9 maintenance tool, where i could manage the Qt 5.9.2 version only. In this case, I ended up reinstalling qt.

Comment: is there a MAC version of the maintenance tool?

Comment: @ChuckB `Once Qt is installed, you can use the Maintenance Tool under <install_dir> to add components and to update or remove installed components.`

Comment: (In Windows 10, this can be accessed via the "Uninstall Qt" entry in the Start Menu)